# swift changing button image appends new image ontop of old

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to change a buttons background image once the button is clicked.

In storyboard I have set a background image for the button

And when the button is clicked I fire:

```
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "list.pdf"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

But this will make the new image being placed ontop of the old one.

But if I fire:

```
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "list.pdf"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

This will only show the new image, so it seems to work.

But why will not `setImage()` work?

Comment: BTW - Please only use tags appropriate to each question. None of your recent questions have had anything to do with Objective-C, Xcode, or the iPhone device.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal.

You did set a background image. When you fire, you have to set a new background image.

`.setImage()` set an image instead of the button title ( `.setTitle()` ). So when fire with `.setImage()` you replace the title, not the background image.

Hope that helps.